# Protecting Docker daemon

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Am I understanding correctly that [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/) discuss how to protect the Docker daemon when commands are issued (`docker run`,...) with a remote machine as the target? When controlling docker locally this does not concern me.

Running Docker swarm does not require this step either as the security between the nodes is handled by Docker [automatically](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/how-swarm-mode-works/pki/). For example, using [Portainer](https://www.portainer.io/) in a swarm with multiple agents does not require extra security steps due to `overlay` network in a swarm being encrypted by default.

Basically, when my target machine will always be `localhost` there are no extra security steps to be taken, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that *anyone* who can run *any* Docker command can almost trivially get unrestricted root-level access on the host:

```
docker run -v/:/host busybox sh
# vi /host/etc/passwd
```

So yes, if you're using a remote Docker daemon, you must run through *every* step in that document, correctly, or your system will get rooted.

If you're using a local Docker daemon and you haven't enabled the extremely dangerous `-H` option, then security is entirely controlled by Unix permissions on the `/var/run/docker.sock` special file.  It's common for that socket to be owned by a `docker` group, and to add local users to that group; again, anyone who can run `docker ps` can also trivially edit the host's `/etc/sudoers` file and grant themselves whatever permissions they want.

So: accessing `docker.sock` implies trust with unrestricted root on the host.  If you're passing the socket into a Docker container that you're trusting to launch other containers, you're implicitly also trusting it to not mount system directories off the host when it does.  If you're trying to launch containers in response to network requests, you need to be insanely careful about argument handling lest a shell-injection attack compromise your system; you are almost always better off finding some other way to run your workload.

In short, just running Docker isn't a free pass on security concerns.  A lot of common practices, if convenient, are actually quite insecure.  A quick Web search for "Docker cryptojacking" can very quickly find you the consequences.

Comment: Just to summarize, that document does not concern me when I don't access the docker remotely, yes? I don't plan on mounting the socket either (other than Portainer). Would you consider using Portainer in production too big of a security risk? Secondly, when you mention "the extremely dangerous `-H`" in the case of the default Portainer compose file https://downloads.portainer.io/portainer-agent-stack.yml it is not a problem as it is within a docker network, correct?

Comment: Anything that has access to the Docker socket at all can root the host.  In the case of Portainer, it's a Docker management tool, so it's kind of necessary to do its work; and for build agents and CI systems using the host's Docker socket is generally considered a little easier to manage than other paths.